# How to obtain Session Handle in SunPKCS11

Tags: java, security, hsm

I am using SoftHSM and am able to generate and store keys in a token. In order to use SunPKCS Interfaces many methods require the session handle and i am at a loss on how to retrieve them. 
Currently i am using SoftHSM and PKCS11 as follows. THe code within the comments are what i tried to work with the SUNPKCS11 interface signatures. 
Any example code on how to wrap and unwrap keys will also be much appreciated. I am attempting to backup keys using PKCS11 from one token to another and if my understanding is right, the approach must be via wrapping....
Sitaraman

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic hereString configName = "softhsm.cfg";
    try {
        // Set up the Sun PKCS 11 provider

        String configName = "/etc/softhsm.cfg";
        Provider p = new SunPKCS11(configName);

        String configName1 = "/etc/softhsm1.cfg";
        Provider p1 = new SunPKCS11(configName1);

        if (-1 == Security.addProvider(p)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not add security provider");
        }
        PKCS11 p11 = PKCS11.getInstance("/usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm.so", "C_GetFunctionList", null, false);

       /* p11.C_GetSessionInfo(0);
        CK_INFO cki = p11.C_GetInfo();

        long[] slots = p11.C_GetSlotList(true);
        String label = new String(p11.C_GetTokenInfo(slots[0]).label);
        Object obj = new Object();
        long sessionhandle = p11.C_OpenSession(slots[0], 1, null, null);

        CK_MECHANISM ckm = new CK_MECHANISM();
        ckm.mechanism       = PKCS11Constants.CKM_RSA_PKCS;
        CK_ATTRIBUTE[] cka = new CK_ATTRIBUTE[1];   
        CK_ATTRIBUTE[] cka1 = new CK_ATTRIBUTE[1];           
        long[] keypair =p11.C_GenerateKeyPair(slots[1], ckm, cka, cka1);
        */
        //System.out.println("No. of slots" + slots.length + "label" + label);
        // Load the key store
        char[] pin = "vit12345".toCharArray();
        char[] pin1 = "User12345".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
        KeyStore ks1 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p1);
        ks.load(null, pin);
        ks1.load(null, pin1);
        Entry e;
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry e1;

        // Generate the key
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", p);
        keyGen.initialize(1024, sr);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey pk = keyPair.getPrivate();

        // Java API requires a certificate chain
        X509Certificate[] chain = generateV3Certificate(keyPair);

        ks.setKeyEntry("ALIAS-GOES-HERE", pk, "1234".toCharArray(), chain);
        //ks1.setKeyEntry("ALIAS-GOES-HERE1", pk, "1234".toCharArray(), chain);
        ks.store(null);
        //ks1.store(null);
        Key k = ks.getKey("ALIAS-GOES-HERE", "1234".toCharArray());
        System.out.println("key string is " + k.toString());
        PrivateKey pk1 = (PrivateKey) k;

        System.out.println("OK");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use approach from SunPKCS11 wrapper like you do in commented block in your sample code.

You can obtain a session handle by the following sample code:

```
CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS initArgs = new CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS();
PKCS11 p11 = PKCS11.getInstance("D:\\cryptoki.dll", "C_GetFunctionList", initArgs, false);
long hSession = p11.C_OpenSession(0, CKF_SERIAL_SESSION| CKF_RW_SESSION, null, null);
char [] pin = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'};
p11.C_Login(hSession, CKU_USER, pin);
// do work
p11.C_Logout(hSession);
p11.C_CloseSession(hSession);
```

For example to generate AES key and obtain a handle to generated key use the following (as an example):

```
        CK_ATTRIBUTE[] aesKeyObject = new CK_ATTRIBUTE[13];

        try
        {
            aesKeyObject[0] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_CLASS, CKO_SECRET_KEY);
            aesKeyObject[1] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK_AES);
            aesKeyObject[2] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_VALUE_LEN, 32);
            aesKeyObject[3] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_TOKEN, true);
            aesKeyObject[4] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_LABEL, label);
            aesKeyObject[5] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_PRIVATE, true);
            aesKeyObject[6] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_EXTRACTABLE, false);
            aesKeyObject[7] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_WRAP, true);
            aesKeyObject[8] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_UNWRAP, true);
            aesKeyObject[9] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_ENCRYPT, true);
            aesKeyObject[10] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_DECRYPT, true);
            aesKeyObject[11] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_TRUSTED, true);
            aesKeyObject[12] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_ID, 1550);

            CK_MECHANISM mech = new CK_MECHANISM(CKM_AES_KEY_GEN);

            long newAESKeyHandle = p11.C_GenerateKey(hSession, mech, aesKeyObject);     
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
```

Then you can work with this handle to use newly generated key.
Also the PKCS11 wrapper has methods for wrapping and unwrapping keys which you can use to backup:

```
public native byte[] C_WrapKey(long hSession,
    CK_MECHANISM pMechanism,
    long hWrappingKey,
    long hKey) throws PKCS11Exception

public native long C_UnwrapKey(long hSession,
    CK_MECHANISM pMechanism,
    long hUnwrappingKey,
    byte[] pWrappedKey,
    CK_ATTRIBUTE[] pTemplate) throws PKCS11Exception
```